# How to remove collection named 'group'?

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally created a collection named 'group'.
How do I remove it.

When I give the following in the mongo console

```
 db.group.drop()
```

I get the following error

```
Fri Jun  7 16:36:39.630 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Object function ( parmsObj ){
     var ret = this.runCommand( { "group" : this._groupFixParms( parmsObj ) } );
     if ( ! ret.ok ){
         throw "group command failed: " + tojson( ret );
     }
     return ret.retval;
} has no method 'drop'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `group` is a method on a database object. So, `db.group` cannot be used to get the actual collection named `group`. Instead, use [`.getCollection()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/):

```
db.getCollection('group').drop()
```